# Draw border or outline on GraphicsPath?

Tags: c#, .net, paint, gdi+

I'm making a map drawing program that behaves a lot like a typical "Paint" program. I'd like for my coastlines to be prominent, so adding a border/outline around my painted path like in the following picture is what I'm aiming for:
[image: land with outlines]

The border should appear real-time as the user paints the "land".

Right now, my software behaves like this:
[image: land with no outlines]

At the moment my painting works with `Graphics.DrawLine()`, but I'm guessing I need to add the lines to a `GraphicsPath` and trace the outline on the path somehow to get the desired effect.

Here's the important part of my code. All drawing is being done in a `Canvas` object I've made, which is just a `PictureBox` with some custom logic:

```
private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isMouseDown) // if a mouse button is being pressed
            {
                if (currentTool == Tools.LandWater) // if the current tool is the land placing tool
                {
                    SetupGraphics(); // pretty much just gr = this.CreateGraphics();

                    Brush penBrush = null;

                    if (IsTextureBrush) // if the canvas object is going to use a texture brush or solid brush
                    {
                        Image texture = this.PaperTexture;
                        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) texture = this.LandTexture1;
                        else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) texture = this.WaterTexture; // if user right clicks, water is placed

                        penBrush = new TextureBrush(texture);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        penBrush = new SolidBrush(BrushColour);
                    }

                    using (Pen p = new Pen(penBrush, this.BrushSize))
                    {
                        p.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
                        p.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
                        p.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset;

                        gr.DrawLine(p, lastMouseLocation, e.Location);

                    }

                    lastMouseLocation = e.Location; // originally set in MouseDown as e.Location       
                }
            }


        }
```

Does anyone have a clue as to where I could even start? I looked around at some Win32 API calls and stuff but none of them work as intended.

Comment: Is this WinForms? One big mistake you're making is trying to draw in your MouseMoved event. Don't do that; figure out what region of your canvas the mouse move changed, invalidate that and do all your drawing in the Paint event handler.

Comment: @DourHighArch I can move my code from MouseMove but at the moment my priority is just getting this outline drawn. Any ideas?

Comment: On mouse down create a list of locations, starting with the clicked point. When the mouse moves, add the new location to the list and invalidate the rectangle from the previous position to the current position. In your Paint handler, draw all the lines in the list using your coast pen. When you detect you have crossed a line between points in your list, stop drawing, flood-fill the interior of your figure and invalidate the bounding box of your list. This is a lot of work; fortunately there are many examples how to do this on the web.

Comment: Use a secondary bitmap with a clean background, which you draw your strokes on in using another clean color. Then you can easily sweep that bitmap in one round and find all pixels that are on edges (that's the pixels that have a neighbor in a different color). Then draw the edges on your current image.

Comment: @DanByström if I understand correctly, you're saying I should scan each pixel in the bitmap until I reach a non-plain pixel (indicating "land") and drawing a point at that location? Wouldn't that be computationally expensive to do it every time the mouse moves?

Comment: Nah. Make it work first, then optimize it. You only need to do this in the region where the change took place. You probaby don't think twice about drawing an image with transparency on top of another one. Then don't worry about having to manipulate the pixels in it, if you do i right. (Just don't ever try to use GetPixel/SetPixel. A kitten will die every time you do.)

Comment: FFS. This needs an actually VALID solution. Has anyone found one yet?

Comment: @Pangamma it's been 2 years and I never did figure this out. I ditched Winforms and tried using Electron and a JS library for drawing which came close. I didn't go any further with it because I hate web development and Electron, imo, is a disease that should die a swift death along with Javascript and all its stupid frameworks.

Comment: @KingDan Yeahhh I finally gave up trying to do it the "cool" way and opted for old school tile method. It's really annoying, but it does work. I was lucky enough to have a rectangular shadow requirement